# Difference of two big files

Tags: grep, sed, awk, diff

I have "test1.csv" and it contains

```
200,400,600,800
100,300,500,700
50,25,125,310
```

and test2.csv and it contains

```
100,4,2,1,7
200,400,600,800
21,22,23,24,25
50,25,125,310
50,25,700,5
```

now

```
diff test2.csv test1.csv > result.csv
```

is different than

```
diff test1.csv test2.csv > result.csv
```

I don't know which is the correct order but I want something else, both of the commands above will output something like

```
2 > 100,4,2,1,7
   3 2,3c3,5
   4 < 100,300,500,700
   5 < 50,25,125,310
   6 \ No newline at end of file
   7 ---
   8 > 21,22,23,24,25
   9 > 50,25,125,310
```

I want to output only the difference, thus results.csv should look like this

```
100,300,500,700
100,4,2,1,7
21,22,23,24,25
50,25,700,5
```

I tried `diff -q` and `diff -s` but they didn't do the trick. Order doesn't matter, what matters is that I want to see only the difference, no > nor < nor blank space.

`grep -FvF` did the trick on smaller files not on big ones

first file contains more than 5 million lines, second file contains 1300.

so results.csv should result in ~4,998,700 lines

I also tried `grep -F -x -v -f`  which didn't work.

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14089/please-can-people-format-code-properly?cb=1

Comment: @Tim i saw your link and i'm an old member so i know the rules but was careless, sorry :) was editing it, and i saw a popup that the post was edited so you did the work for me and I'm thankful Sir.

Comment: `50,25,125,310` is common to both file..you need to remove that from your desired output..

Comment: Should the order be preserved?

Comment: @kos the order of numbers in each row yes, the way the rows are displayed, no i don't care about that

Comment: sort of depends on what you want to do with the information, diff, IMO, is for making a patch. At any rate, I am now sure of your best tool, diff, grep, awk, or perl .

Comment: If a line appears two times in the first file but none in the second file, should the line be displayed once or twice?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sounds like a job for `comm`:

```
$ comm -3 <(sort test1.csv) <(sort test2.csv)
100,300,500,700
    100,4,2,1,7
    21,22,23,24,25
    50,25,700,5
```

As explained in `man comm`:

```
   -1     suppress column 1 (lines unique to FILE1)

   -2     suppress column 2 (lines unique to FILE2)

   -3     suppress column 3 (lines that appear in both files)
```

So, the `-3` means that only lines that are unique to one of the files will be printed. However, those are indented according to which file they were found in. To remove the tab, use:

```
$ comm -3 <(sort test1.csv) <(sort test2.csv) | tr -d '\t'
100,300,500,700
100,4,2,1,7
21,22,23,24,25
50,25,700,5
```

In this case, you don't really even need to sort the files and you can simplify the above to:

```
comm -3 test1.csv test2.csv | tr -d '\t' > difference.csv
```

Comment: You haven't been fooled by the spaces after the `200,[...]` line huh? :)

Comment: @kos no, I removed trailing spaces from the files first. I assumed the OP's files don't actually have them.

Answer (score 6):

Using `grep` with `bash` process substitution:

```
$ cat <(grep -vFf test2.csv test1.csv) <(grep -vFf test1.csv test2.csv)
100,300,500,700
100,4,2,1,7
21,22,23,24,25
50,25,700,5
```

To save the output as `results.csv`:

```
cat <(grep -vFf test2.csv test1.csv) <(grep -vFf test1.csv test2.csv) >results.csv
```

- `<()` is the [`bash` process substitution pattern](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)
- `grep -vFf test2.csv test1.csv` will find the lines unique to only `test1.csv`
- `grep -vFf test1.csv test2.csv` will find the lines unique to only `test2.csv`
- Finally we are summing up the results by `cat`

Or as [Oli suggested](https://askubuntu.com/posts/comments/915620?noredirect=1), you can use command grouping also:

```
$ { grep -vFf test2.csv test1.csv; grep -vFf test1.csv test2.csv; }
100,300,500,700
100,4,2,1,7
21,22,23,24,25
50,25,700,5
```

Or just run one after another, as they are both writing to STDOUT they will ultimately get added:

```
$ grep -vFf test2.csv test1.csv; grep -vFf test1.csv test2.csv
100,300,500,700
100,4,2,1,7
21,22,23,24,25
50,25,700,5
```

Comment: Why `cat` two redirected commands? Why not just run one then the other? `grep ... ; grep ...` or `{ grep ... ; grep ... ; }` if you wanted to do something with the collective output.

Comment: @Oli Thanks..thats a great idea..i did not think of that..

Answer (score 4):

If the order of rows is not relevant, use `awk` or `perl`:

```
awk '{seen[$0]++} END {for (i in seen) {if (seen[i] == 1) {print i}}}' 1.csv 2.csv
```

---

Use `grep` to get the common lines and filter those out:

```
grep -hxvFf <(grep -Fxf 1.csv 2.csv) 1.csv 2.csv
```

The internal grep gets the common lines, then the external grep finds lines which don't match these common lines.

Comment: Your awk command just re-implements `sort | uniq -u`, which gives the wrong answer when one file contains duplicate lines.  For grep, I'd say "inner"/"outer", not "internal"/"external".

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, it does and who are you to say that's the wrong result?

Comment: Wrong in the sense that it's not exactly what the question asked for, in that corner case.  It might be what someone wants, but you should point out the difference between what your `awk` will print and what the `comm -3` and `diff` answers will print.

Comment: @PeterCordes again, who are you to say that? Until the OP says that's what they want, I don't care if the output differs from that of `comm -3`. I don't see any reason why *I* should explain that. If you want to edit in a note, feel free.

Comment: The OP said he wants the difference.  That's not always what your program produces.  A program that produces the same output for one testcase, but doesn't satisfy the description as written for all cases, requires a heads up.  I'm here to say that, and it's true regardless of who I am or who you are.  I added a note.

Comment: @PeterCordes who you are you is relevant, since that is a test case that the OP hasn't given. Until they give that test case, and then the output shows that you say is right, you are wrong.

Comment: The OP described in words that he wanted the DIFFERENCES between two files.  You can't require every question to provide exhaustive testcases for every corner case of their clearly worded description.

Comment: @PeterCordes and neither can you come up with possible purely imaginary test cases. For all I know, neither file never has a duplicated line, and further, OP worded it in the simplest way for the case with no duplicate lines, never thinking of this imaginary situation. WRITING IT IN ALL CAPS DOESN'T MAKE YOU RIGHTER.

Comment: Sorry, I should have use *italics* for emphasis.  So your position is that it doesn't matter if your program makes assumptions the OP didn't say you could?  As long as your output matches the one testcase provided, it doesn't matter if the behaviour doesn't match the English-language description of the desired behaviour in some corner cases?  I can't agree with that position, unless there's a big gain in efficiency or code size.  Even then, I'd always mention any corner case I knew my code didn't handle the way I thought the OP wanted.

Comment: @PeterCordes my position is that I don't see your test case as a valid one, so whatever you say predicated on that test case is irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

### Use the `--*-line-format=...` options of `diff`

You can tell `diff` exactly what you need - explained below:

```
diff --old-line-format='%L' --new-line-format='%L' --unchanged-line-format='' f1.txt f2.txt
```

It is possible to specify the output of diff in a very detailed way, similar to a `printf` number format.

The lines from the first file, `test1.csv` are called "old" lines, and the lines from the second, `test2.csv`, are "new" lines. That makes sense when `diff` is used to see what changed in a file.

The options we need are the ones to set the format for "old" lines, "new" lines, and "unchanged" lines.
The formats we need are very simple:
For the changed lines, new and old, we want to output only the text of the lines. `%L` is the format symbol for the line text.
For the unchanged lines, we want to show nothing.

With this, we can write options like `--old-line-format='%L'`, and put it all together, using your example data:

```
$ diff --old-line-format='%L' --new-line-format='%L' --unchanged-line-format='' test1.csv test2.csv
100,4,2,1,7
100,300,500,700
21,22,23,24,25
50,25,700,5
```

### Notes on performance

Because the files have different size, try to exchange the input files if it does not matter, it could be that the inner workings of `diff` can handle one way better than the other. Better is either needing less memory, or less computation.

There is an optimisation option for using `diff` with large files: `--speed-large-files`. It uses assumptions about the file structure, so it's not clear whether it helps in your case, but worth trying it.

The format options are described in the [`man diff`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/diff.1.html) under `--LTYPE-line-format=LFMT`.

Answer (score 3):

Since the order doesn't need to be preserved, simply:

```
sort test1.csv test2.csv | uniq -u
```

- `sort test1.csv test2.csv`: merges and sorts `test1.csv` and `test2.csv`
- `uniq -u`: prints only the lines which have no duplicate

Comment: That does not work if one file contains a line two times, that does not appear in the other file. Both occurences would be in a `diff` result.